# Local notification not working on IOS - ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, localnotification

I added local notification in my ionic application using the below code and was working good.but there is an issue on iOS

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: 1,
  text: 'Single ILocalNotification',
  sound: isAndroid? 'file://sound.mp3': 'file://beep.caf',
  data: { secret: key }
});
```

This is not working on IOS ,if we open application from background.

Error replicate steps.

1.Open applicaton

2.Minimize application in the background

3.Open application from background.

4.After this the notification was not showing on the status bar,but we can here the notification sound